# XDF file not saved in RxOptions "OutDataPath"

Tags: python, revoscalepy

I am running a small Python RevoscalePy script to import a file into an XDF file.

```
# [RESULTS_LOCATION] = ['C:\\\\Temp\\\\Data\\\\Results']
RxOptions.set_option("OutDataPath", [RESULTS_LOCATION])
...
infile = os.path.join(st.SAMPLE_DATA_DIR,'claims.txt')
rx_import(input_data = infile, output_file = 'claims.xdf',
    overwrite = True)
```

The file `claims.xdf` is not saved in `C:\Temp\Data\Results`, but in the directory of the `.py` script (the default according to documentation). Why?

**Update**

With the following, it works:

```
outfile = os.path.join(st.RESULTS_LOCATION,'claims.xdf')

rx_import(input_data = infile, output_file = outfile,
    overwrite = True)
```

Comment: But do you know why it happens?

Comment: This is same as rx_import(input_data = infile, output_file = 'C:\\Temp\\Data\\Results\\claims.xdf',
    overwrite = True)

Comment: I think you missed the point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/python-reference/revoscalepy/rxoptions#outdatapath

Comment: I got your point. Thanks for clarification.